# Looping walk animation doesn't work

Tags: unity, animation

I have a walk cycle, and even though I have ticked, `loop walk` and `loop pose`, the looping fails, I think it's because of the red indicator which probably says something about loop mismatch. The animation is from mixamo, and it should be a loopable animation, but it's not an `in-place` animation, so maybe that's what that means? Please let me know what this means and how should I fix it?: [image]

EDIT: [image]  As per the documentation linked in the comments, it seems all 4 dots don't have to turn green, but, the animation doesn't loop.

Comment: Could you specify how the looping fails?
Are you using root motion?

Comment: It looks like [this is pretty well described in the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoopingAnimationClips.html). Have you tried using the method outlined there?

Comment: @Mattias , the looping fails, i.e. after the animation clip plays it doesn't start from beginning, it's just stuck and I can see that in the animator

Comment: @DMGregory , please take a look at the screenshot above, and it seems all four dots are not being green seems normal as per the doc. But, the animation becomes stuck after playing once, even though I have loop time and loop pose ticked.

Comment: @Mattias , the animation was root motion when downloaded, do I have to specific stuffs to let unity know that it is root motion? I haven't done anything for that because, tuts I followed didn't mention them, but, it does actually translate, so I think root motion is working

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much didn't think there was an apply button there, just wasted 2 hours: [image]

Comment: Argh. I hate when that happens. Same thing happened to me after a LONG setup on some stations in EVE-Online.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have downloaded the animation from mixamo you need to usse Ctrl+D to make a duplicate and than edit it because the orignal wont edit, even thought it give the option of edit